# firefox, internet explorer and msn instantly crash after update KB2670838

Tags: windows-7, firefox, internet-explorer, crash, windows-live-messenger

After installing the optional update KB2670838, IE/FF/MSN instantly crash at starting up those applications. I've done some system restores and installed this update twice to be sure that this is the update that is causing this.

Anyone else experiencing this problem? 
And did you fixed it while having KB2670838 installed? If so, how?

Thanks in advance!

P.s. chrome doesn't crash. Haven't tried other browsers. But it seems that this is affecting browsers.

EDIT:
Couldn't add 64-bit as a tag, because of the 5 tag limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with update KB2670838. A description of the problem and the recommended solution can be found at http://answers.microsoft.com at [After installation of update KB2670838 Windows 7 keeps crashing to blue screen](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/after-installation-of-update-kb2670838-win-7-keeps/66be9f5a-2257-4c4a-9c9c-5dc6f0f55d37?page=5). According to the webpage at http://answers.microsoft.com you should just remove this update.

Comment: I saw that article. I already did a system restore. But not everyone has this problem, thats why i asked the question. But i guess it doesn't matter anyway.